# Elasticsearch query with match and filtered

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal

I have two requests simple which work. But together it does not work anymore.
I use elasticsearch 1.4 and drupal 7.

This query works and results it's ok :

```
    $searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'match'=> [
                'title' => [
                    'query' => "vivre et comprendre le cancer",
                    'operator' => "and"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

This second query works and results it's ok :

```
    $searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

**BUT** together i have an error : nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"filtered\"];

```
    $searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'match'=> [
                'title' => [
                    'query' => "vivre et comprendre le cancer",
                    'operator' => "and"
                ]
            ],
            'filtered'=> [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `match` query inside the `filtered > query` one

```
$searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'query' => [
                   'match'=> [
                     'title' => [
                        'query' => "vivre et comprendre le cancer",
                        'operator' => "and"
                     ]
                   ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ]
                        ]

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks you very mutch Val :)